# Order by integer with blank fields at the bottom

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We're rewriting our CMS at the moment and we want our clients to be able to re-order items in a table using a "position" field. So, if they mark an items as position 1 it goes at the top, then position 2 underneath it etc.

The problem is that we don't want to them to have to fill in a position every time, only if they want to re-order something so the position field will often be blank. So you might have the following...

Car - 1

Bike - 2

House

Computer

Dog

This causes a problem because if you use the following SQL...

```
SELECT ProductName FROM Products ORDER BY Position DESC;
```

All the blank ones go to the top, not the bottom.

Can they be put into the correct order using a SQL statement?

Comment: David B has the right answer, sort by two expressions.  There are a couple of alternatives for the first expresssion, the "trick" is getting all the non-NULL values grouped together.  If 'Position' is numeric, you can easily generate a 0 for all non-NULL values to get them grouped together    ... ORDER BY Position-Position DESC, Position DESC

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
SELECT ProductName
FROM Products
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN Position is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
  Position
```

If you want to order by Position Descending while maintaining nulls at the bottom, this will do it:

```
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN Position is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
  Position desc
```

If you want consistent sorting (you might be paging), then add ProductName or ProductID on the end to break all the ties between unpositioned products.

```
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN Position is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
  Position,
  ProductID
```

Comment: +1 @David: I think this is the right answer (sort by two expressions rather than 1).  The only thing I see is that you missed the DESC keyword (from the OP question).

Comment: @David: You didn't miss the DESC keyword, I got it wrong. (I can't edit my previous comment. (D'Oh!) I got the DESC keyword the sample SQL in the OP question, but it's not what the OP wants. If I absolutely insisted on using the the DESC keyword (and I have no reason to other than I might like arithmetic expressions and unnecessary obsfucation)...   ORDER BY Position-Position DESC, -1*Position DESC

Comment: There should be a little round red button with an x in it that will allow you to delete your own comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  ProductName
FROM    Products
ORDER BY
        COALESCE(position, (SELECT MAX(position) + 1 FROM Products))
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  ProductName
        FROM    Products
        WHERE   position IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY
                position
        ) q
UNION ALL
SELECT  ProductName
FROM    Products
WHERE   position IS NULL
```

This will be more efficient, since the first subquery will use the index on `position` for ordering is there is one.

Comment: He wants to order by asc, not desc. Instead of -1, it should be (select max(position)+1 from products), and ProductName should be the second order by criteria.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the the job for you.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [Position] [int] NULL,
    [Title] [varchar](15) NULL
) 
GO

INSERT INTO Test Values(1, 'P1')
INSERT INTO Test Values(2, 'P2')
INSERT INTO Test Values(NULL, 'P3')
INSERT INTO Test Values(NULL, 'P4')
INSERT INTO Test Values(NULL, 'P5')
GO

SELECT Title + ' - ' +  CASE  
    WHEN POSITION IS NULL THEN ''
    ELSE CAST(Position AS CHAR(3))
    END
FROM Test
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Position is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 0):

**Only use NULLs when necessary**

you can easily eliminate the use of nulls, and the resulting sort problem, by defaulting "unset" rows to the integer max value:

- UPDATE Products SET Position=2147483647 WHERE Position IS NULL
- set the column to NOT NULL, add a default value of 2147483647
- use your ORDER BY as intended
- in your app or in your load query, suppress the display of any value of 2147483647

here is a sample load:

```
SELECT 
    ProductName
        ,CASE
             WHEN Position=2147483647 THEN NULL  --or cast this as a varchar and use 'N/A'
             ELSE Position
         END
    FROM ...
```

If you must use nulls, do it this way:

```
SELECT
    ProductName
        ,Position
    FROM Test
    ORDER BY COALESCE(Position,2147483647)
```

Comment: hhm. I'd use NULLs and ISNULL in the ORDER BY. NULL is better than an arbritary value and COALESCE is slower

Comment: if every row has a value you don't have to use ISNULL or COALESCE, and that would be the the fastest.